# Qcheckbox minimum one option is always checked in QT -c++

Tags: c++, qt, qcheckbox

I have a QT application with qcheckboxes. I would like to achive that one checkbox is always checked and i can check as much as i want, but one is always must be checked. How can i do this?

Comment: Connect the signals. If you detect that there's no others that are checked, you can automatically select whichever should be checked.

Comment: You can use a QButtonGroup and make it non exclusive and connect to the https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonToggled-1 signal

Comment: ty @drescherjm it works too! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but I'd suggest just using signals.

Somewhere, probably constructor, you would connect the signal

```
connect( chkOne, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, &Test::onCheckboxOne );
```

Then, in the function you've connected it to, simply check whether anything else is checked. For this, I used a variable called `total_checked`.

```
void Test::onCheckboxOne( bool checked ) {
    disconnect( chkOne, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, &Test::onCheckboxOne );
    if ( !checked ) {
        if ( total_checked == 1 )
            this->chkOne->setCheckState( Qt::Checked );
        else
            --total_checked;
    } else {
        ++total_checked;
    }
    connect( chkOne, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, &Test::onCheckboxOne );
}
```

This would become impractical if you have a lot of checkboxes, unless (once non are selected), you want a specific checkbox set, in which case the above would be a handler for all checkbox signals.